# Chaning height of UIView

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiview, height

I'm trying to change the height and width of UIView using Swift and it's not working. Tried both codes below, still no progress.

```
self.contentView.frame.size.height = 100

self.contentView.bounds.size.height = 100
```

`contentView` is a subview of the main view.

Comment: If you are using the Autolayout then it will not work. For that you have to take the outlet of constraint and then change it!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using constraints. And when you use constraints you should change not the frame but constraints itself. It should looks like this:

In storyboard, pick height constraint for your view and create outlet to controller:

[image]

And then change it's constant value:

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

func changeHeight() {
  heightConstraint.constant = 200
// uncomment to perform changes with animation
//  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) { () -> Void in
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
//  }
}
```